# How to create Jquery Suggest with Sphinx Search?

Tags: php, jquery, search, sphinx, autosuggest

can some one give me an idea to build jquery Suggest with sphinx search?
i am newbie with sphinx
i already have my searchd run and i can make a simple search.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1. prepare list of phrases you want to
   use in the suggestion list (it can
   be most popular phrases based on
   your data or just search phrases
   people made when they used your
   search)
2. if you want to use Sphinx create an
   index with some not very low
   min_prefix_len
   (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len)
   based on the above list of phrases.
   Here
   http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/sphinx/61807/
   (use some translator to translate
   from russian) Andrew Aksyonoff
   (author of Sphinx) described another
   way of doing the same - using mysql
   fulltext search for searching and
   Sphinx' --buildstops feature only for
   building the most popular words
   list.
3. use jquery to send request to your
   application on each key press, your
   application should make request to
   the index (or mysql) from point 2,
   i.e. once you enter 'Goo' your
   application will return 'Google
   maps', 'Google earth' etc. Ensure
   you use proper document ranking to
   obtain good results.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexer and --buildstops to get a list of top words.

Import the words into a database table. (and a autoincrement column to get a unique id)

Create a sphinx index on this table - and enable min_prefix_len

Setup a script that runs the users query against this index, and looks up the full words
in the database, and returns it to the Javascript client library.